# What is the mathematical model formula corresponding to this gam model fit in R?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

If I have a generalised additive model how would I write this in the correct manner in a scientific paper? For example:

```
set.seed(10)
RandData <- rnorm(8760*2)
America <- rep(c('NewYork','Miami'),each=8760)

Date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("1991-01-01 00:00"), 
           to=as.POSIXct("1991-12-31 23:00"), length=8760)

DatNew <- data.frame(Loc = America,
                     Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")),
                     Tod = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%H")),
                     Temp = RandData,
                     DecTime = rep(seq(1, length(RandData)/2) / (length(RandData)/2),
                                   2))
require(mgcv)
mod1 <- gam(Temp ~ Loc + s(Doy) + s(Doy,by = Loc) +
  s(Tod) + s(Tod,by = Loc),data = DatNew, method = "ML")
```

So, if I wanted to write the Temperature of both locations can be described by the following model... How would I write this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Leaving off the other calls to `gam` (e.g. `data`, `method`), your model formula is:

```
Temp ~ Loc + s(Doy) + s(Doy,by = Loc) + s(Tod) + s(Tod,by = Loc)
```

The help file for [gam formulas is here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/formula.gam.html) and is where I'm getting my information. The `s()` terms indicate a smooth function in that term, when a `by` tag is included within `s()`, that indicates the smooth function is multiplied by the corresponding term. The terms without `s()` around them are ordinary linear terms. So, your model can be written as:

$$ {\rm Temp} = {\rm Loc} + f_{1}({\rm Doy}) + f_{2}({\rm Doy})\cdot {\rm Loc} + f_{3}({\rm Tod}) + f_{4}({\rm Tod})\cdot {\rm Loc} + \varepsilon $$

where $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are smooth functions estimated by the model by maximum likelihood. You may consider replacing the variable names with symbols (e.g. $T$ instead of ${\rm Temp}$) but this is how you would write it, using the same variable names as in your `R` code.

Comment: Can you think of s(Doy,by=Loc) as an interaction term? Is f(Doy)*Loc the same thing as a smooth function of the interaction between Doy and Loc i.e. f(Doy*Loc)?

Comment: @B_Miner, I suppose you could think of it as an interaction in some sense. It tells you how, in one particular way, the effect of `Doy` is different when `Loc` takes on different values. But, it is **not** the same as f(Doy*Loc). The space of functions defined by f(Doy)*Loc is different from that defined f(Doy*Loc) and they mostly do not overlap (except when, for example f(x) = x). A more general "interaction" would be the function f(Doy,Loc), which is far more general than both f(Doy*Loc) and f(Doy)*Loc

Comment: Thanks! I see that one could produce a term closer (?) to f(Doy*Loc) perhaps by using the formula s(Doy,Loc) in the gam call.