# Writing out the mathematical model formula of gam

Tags: r, model

I am trying to write out the mathematical formula for a GAM which i have but mathematical equations are not my strong suit. Would anyone be able to tell me if the following equation if current for the model which i have fitted in r? I think its partly correct but don't like the look of some bits (the xi's for example)

written euqation

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
Y_{i} \sim \operatorname{Neg} \operatorname{Bin}\left(\mu_{i}, \theta\right) \\
\eta_{i}=\mu_{i}=\beta_{0}+x_{i}+f_{1}\left(x_{i}\right)+f_{2}\left(x_{i}\right)+x_{i}+f_{4}\left(x_{i}\right)+x_{i}+x_{i}+x_{i}+x_{i}+f_5\left(\operatorname{lon}_{i}, \text { lat }_{i}\right)
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Model in R;

```
mod = gam(TB ~ offset(log(Population)) + s(Indigenous, k = 10, bs = "cr") + s(Urbanisation, k = 10, bs = "cr") +
              s(Density, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Poverty + s(Poor_Sanitation, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Unemployment + Timeliness +
              as.factor(Year) + Region + s(lon, lat, bs = "sos"), 
              data = TBdata, 
              family = nb(link = 'log'))
```

Comment: Have you seen [What is the mathematical model formula corresponding to this gam model fit in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32013/what-is-the-mathematical-model-formula-corresponding-to-this-gam-model-fit-in-r)

Comment: @dipetkov Yeh I did notice that post earlier, it is very helpful, although I still struggled to translate that over to my model.